# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'worklet.__workletHash.toString')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Got this error when using react native reanimated carousel. Anyone with a work around?

I was trying to use react reanimated carousel but every I try to run the code its giving me the same error,

Am a junior developer and I have failed to get any relatable solutions

This is my code:

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity ,SafeAreaView, ImageBackground, Platform, ScrollView, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import Carousel from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';
import { sliderData } from '../../model/data.js';
import BannerSlider from '../BannerSlider';
import { windowWidth } from '../../utils/Dimensions.js';

const Home = ({navigation}) =>{
    const renderBanner = ({item,index})=>{
        return(
            <BannerSlider data={item}/>
        )
    }
    const [isLloaded] = useFonts({
        'Roboto-Medium': require('../../assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf')
    })

    if(!isLloaded){
        return null
    }
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView  style={{padding:20}}>     
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'space-between',marginBottom:20}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold', fontFamily:'Roboto-Medium'}}>Hello , Edrine</Text>
                    <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/user-profile.jpg')} style={{width:35,height:35,}} imageStyle={{borderRadius:25}}/>
                 </View>   
                 <View style={{
                    flex:1,
                    flexDirection:'row'
                    ,alignItems:'center',
                    borderColor:'#c6c6c6',
                    borderWidth:1 ,
                    borderRadius:5,
                    paddingHorizontal:10,
                    paddingVertical:8,
                    
                }}>
                    <Feather name="search" size={20} color='#c9c9c9' style={{marginRight:5}}/>
                    <TextInput placeholder='Search' style={{flex:1}}/>
                </View>  
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'space-between',marginVertical:15}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold'}}>Upcoming Games</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity >
                        <Text style={{color:'#0aada8'}}>See All</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>      
            
                    <Carousel
                    key={(item)=>item.id}
                    loop
                    width={windowWidth}
                    height={windowWidth / 2}
                    autoPlay={true}
                    data={sliderData}
                    onSnapToItem={(index) => console.log('current index:', index)}
                    scrollAnimationDuration={1000}
                    renderItem={()=>(<renderBanner/>)}
                    />
           
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:"#fff",
      paddingTop:Platform.OS==='android' ? 20 : 0,
    }
})

export default Home
```

this is the entire error:

```js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'worklet.__workletHash.toString')

This error is located at:
    in IScrollViewGesture
    in Unknown (created by Home)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by Home)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in SafeAreaView (created by Home)
    in Home (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Screen)
    in MaybeFreeze (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

```
 Type Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'worklet workletHash.toString')
```

Comment: Check your question, you didn't post your code, this way we cannot help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This was a reanimated error,

its solved using
npx expo start -c and it worked

expo start -c    wasn't working for me